# Price filter on configurable products

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product, price, layered-navigation, filter

I'd like to understand how price filter works on configurable products.

Let's say I have one config. products with 2 linked simple products.

The simple product prices are 100$ and 200$, so that the configurable one base price will be 100$.

Let's say customers filter price from 150$ to 200$.

Will that product be listed?

If not, how to show it?

Hope I was clear.
Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

This information is stored in the catalog_product_price_index table as min_price and max_price.  So, yes, it should be listed.

Comment: thanks, but do I have to change magento filter funcionality?

Comment: You shouldn't have to change anything.  That query is generated by default if you are using layered navigation.

Comment: I've investigated on the query and it seems exclude those results because the it is like 'where min_price >= $minprice and $max_price <= $maxprice'. So I think the filtering query should be modified.